# How to add or use functions on Atom snippets?

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I want to know if it is possible to create or call functions to use on snippets in the Atom editor. If possible, how do I do it ? Maybe using lodash or something similar ?

I want to use something like uppercase(), downcase(), filePath().

My problem is that I want to generate something like this line below:

```
import Hello from 'components/atoms/hello/Hello';
```

My snippet would be something like this:

```
import $1 from 'components/atoms/downcase($1)/$1';
```

Or:

```
import camelCase($1) from 'components/atoms/$1/camelCase($1)';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is still an opened issue. So it's seems there is no solution right now for this, sorry.

[Here is the issue.](https://github.com/atom/snippets/issues/109)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use some lodash or underscore to make this possible. I'm gonna look more into Atom code to see if I can manage monkey patch or something then. Thanks

Comment: Good idea :) Even better : you can try to get in touch with the community thanks to the link I posted before, and contribute to this enhancement. Anyway, give us some feedback here, I think a lot of us are waiting for this feature.